# I want to write a fixed value of a variable JSON

Tags: java, android, json

So my problem is the following:

```
holder.buttonViewID.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    toggle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, rmfcart , null, null);
                    try {
                        pack.put("imgid", resID2);
                        pack.put("desc", descval);
                        Log.d("PERSODEBUG", pack.toString());
                        trolly.put(itemID, pack.toString());
                        Log.d("PERSODEBUG", trolly.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
[...]
```

pack and trolly are JSONObjects, 
trolly is behaving perfectly fine, i can add items to it and remove them it behaves as expected but the problem is with pack. with every change all pack instances already added to trolly get modified. 
for instance:

```
if i add an item to trolly:
{"2":{"imgid":2131165314,"desc":"test1"}}
if i add a 2nd item:
{"2":{"imgid":2131165330,"desc":"test2"},"3":{"imgid":2131165330,"desc":"test2"}}
```

As you see both old and new instances of pack get modified inside trolly, 
can anyone tell me how can i write a fixed string of pack instance inside trolly to avoid this problem ? I did try a few things like ,
as you can see above the toString() didn't have any effect.

thanks a lot

Comment: don't use the same `resID2` and `descval` in each `pack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud create new instance of pack every time before adding rather than global instance

```
JSONObject pack = new JSONObject(); // new instance
pack.put("imgid", resID2);
pack.put("desc", descval);
Log.d("PERSODEBUG", pack.toString());
trolly.put(itemID, pack.toString());
```